# Rough paths theory - why is it natural?

Tags: pr.probability, soft-question

First a disclaimer, I know very little rigorously about the subject and I may have many misconceptions in what follows so please correct me if I’m wrong about anything. Also none of this is meant to be a critique of the theory. I’m not qualified to do so in the first place, and I’m very sure I’m missing something fundamental here.

But anyway, the main thing I want to ask is “how is rough paths not cheating?”. From what I understand, some paths are too rough to be integrated in the usual sense, in their words they don’t carry enough “data” by themselves to do calculus. So you just... postulate additional data, namely their behaviour under iterated integrals and then you can do it. Morally, why is this okay?

In what way is this theory then a natural extension of probability theory instead of just giving ourselves additional structure that didn’t exist in the first place?

Comment: This is discussed in various places, like for example the introduction of my lecture notes http://www.hairer.org/notes/RoughPaths.pdf. Basically, it's just the closure of plain old smooth functions in a weak topology that's still strong enough for solutions to ODEs to be continuous.